# Rewrite names of files in a subdirectory with htaccess gives error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

im working on a simple html/css website in an apache server

i changed urls from [www.mydomain.com/about.html](http://www.mydomain.com/about.html) to [www.mydomain.com/a-propos-de-nous](http://www.mydomain.com/a-propos-de-nous) for all fils in main directory with a htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule a-propos-de-nous /about.html
```

its working perfectly!

but when i try to do the same for files in a sub directory /en , it gives me error 404 :
i created a new file (en.htaccess) in sub directory /en , the content of the file is :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule about-us /en/about.html [L]
```

i expected to have [www.mydomain.com/about-us](http://www.mydomain.com/about-us) working, but its gives me error 404.

but i have always the 404 error ,
i missed something ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Try adding `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` in your 2nd htaccess file on the top and then try once.

Comment: unfortunately still not working : error 404

Comment: "i created a new file (en.htaccess)" - The file needs to be called `.htaccess`, not `en.htaccess`. (?!)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rewrite `www.mydomain.com/about-us` then rewrite rule must go in root .htaccess since there is no `/en/` in your original URI. Just change your root .htaccess to this:

```bash
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule a-propos-de-nous about.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^about-us en/about.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hello , i just try it , and refresh , it gived me a diferent error :
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."
...
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: all files in the site gives this error 500 ,(files in root + files in subdirectory /en)

Comment: I have tested these rules on my Apache and there is no syntax issue that can cause this error. Do you have other rules in this .htaccess as well?  Can you check Apache error.log file and see reason of the error?

Comment: i deleted the htaccess in the folder /en , i kept just 1 .htaccess file in root, i have 500 error , i checked the error log : i have this :
 /var/www/mydomain.com/web/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: www.mydomain.com/about-us

the content of .htaccess  : 

`code`
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^about-us en/about.html [L,NC]
`code`

Comment: Please provide this htaccess in question so that I can understand it better

Comment: Try last rule without flags i.e. have this line only: `RewriteRule ^about-us en/about.html`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your htaccess rules file to following once. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore

Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule about-us en/about.html [L]
```

Comment: @FreeMoor, I have answered here, we could discuss it here, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,
what do you mean by "changing your htaccess rules file to following once"
Im working on private navigation window, and i press ctrl + f5 ,but still not working

Comment: @FreeMoor, Did it work for you?

Comment: still not working

Comment: @FreeMoor, ok mention full path of your htaccess and en folder in comments and let me see what's going on here.

Comment: as i mentionned earlier , i have 2 files htaccess:
1 - .htaccess in web/ for all html files in folder web (its working well)
2 - en.htaccess in web/en/ for all html files in folder en/ (its not working)

Comment: @FreeMoor, yeah I get that. But could you please post their complete path details. Eg: `/singh/test/bla_bla/.htaccess` and `/singh/tyest/bla_bla/en/.htaccess`?

Comment: the site is deployed in web :

web/.htaccess
web/en/en.htaccess

Comment: @FreeMoor, you need to change file's name from `en.htaccess` TO `.htaccess` in en folder.

Comment: i did it and i deleted the htaccess in the folder /en , i kept just 1 .htaccess file in root, i have 500 error , i checked the error log : i have this : /var/www/mydomain.com/web/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: www.mydomain.com/about-us the content of .htaccess : code Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^about-us en/about.html [L,NC] code